# Piecewise integration doesn't evaluate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, piecewise

I'm trying to integrate the following function:
$$q(d, \theta) = q_x(d, \theta) + q_y(d, \theta) - 2q_x(d, \theta) q_y(d, \theta)$$
where $q_x(d, \theta) = \min\left(2 - d\cos\theta, d\cos\theta\right)$ and $q_y(d, \theta)$ is defined likewise with $\sin$.
So I defined the following functions in Mathematica:

```mathematica
qx[d_, o_] := Min[2 - d*Cos[o], d*Cos[o]]
qy[d_, o_] := Min[2 - d*Sin[o], d*Sin[o]]
q[d_, o_] := PiecewiseExpand[qx[d, o] + qy[d, o] - 2*qx[d, o]*qy[d, o]]
```

but when I try and integrate, Mathematica doesn't calculate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} q(d, \theta) \,d\theta$:
[image]
Nothing works to simplify that: `PiecewiseExpand`, `FullSimplify` don't work. Interestingly enough, integrating $q_x$ and $q_y$ work:
[image]
What's going on here? Why can't it handle the product of the two? I've tried just doing `Integrate[qx[d, o]*qy[d, o], {o, 0, Pi/2}]` with similar failure.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

qx[d_, o_] := Min[2 - d*Cos[o], d*Cos[o]]
qy[d_, o_] := Min[2 - d*Sin[o], d*Sin[o]]
q[d_, o_] := PiecewiseExpand[qx[d, o] + qy[d, o] - 2*qx[d, o]*qy[d, o]]
```

[`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) needs a numeric value for `d`. However, it is extremely slow.

```
int[d_?NumericQ] := Integrate[q[d, o], {o, 0, Pi/2}]

Plot[int[d], {d, -1.5, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Using [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) is much faster but still quite slow .

```
int2[d_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[q[d, o], {o, 0, Pi/2}]

Plot[int2[d], {d, -1.5, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it the case that `d` needs to be numerical? I can’t seem to find the reason in `Integrate`’s documentation. It worked fine with `qx`, so what gives with `q`? I wanted to find the symbolic expression for the integral, so it would be best if `d` was symbolic.

Comment: Mathematica cannot do all integrals symbolically. When you encounter an integral that it cannot perform symbolically, you can try to find some clever trick or do the integral numerically. I don't know a clever trick that works here so I did it numerically.

Comment: OK, I did do the integral by hand so I know it’s possible to do symbolically. But, it seems like Mathematica cannot. Perhaps I can try a clever trick by writing it as `Piecewise` functions, and explicitly defining cases in terms of `o <= function of d`. Thanks.